# Web Forms - Session object is null when going through custom IRouteHandler

Tags: asp.net, session, webforms, iroutehandler

I'm having an issue in ASP WebForms where `HttpContext.Current.Session` is null if my request goes through a custom `IRouteHandler`.

I have seen many answers where people are giving advices on how to access the Session object inside a custom `IRouteHandler` but this is not my issue. I don't need to access the session object in the handler, I just don't want it to be null when using that handler.

This is the code for the custom handler:

```
public class LanguageRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{
    private static readonly Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        Logger.Debug("GetHttpHandler");

        //return new LanguageHttpHandler(this, requestContext);

        string rest = requestContext.RouteData.Values["rest"] as string;
        string destinationPath = "";

        string language = requestContext.RouteData.Values["language"] as string;

        string queryString = "?";
        NameValueCollection queries = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString;

        foreach (string myKey in queries.AllKeys)
        {
            queryString += (myKey + "=" + queries[myKey] + "&");
        }
        HttpContext.Current.Items["qs"] = queryString.Substring(0, queryString.Length - 1);
        if (rest == null || rest == "")
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Items["lng"] = language;

            destinationPath = "~/Content.aspx";
            EasyUrlHelper.Current.OriginalPath = destinationPath.Replace("~/", "");

            HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(string.Concat("~/Content.aspx", queryString == "?"));
            return BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath("~/Content.aspx", typeof(Page)) as Page;
        }
        else
        {
            if (rest.EndsWith("aspx"))
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Items["lng"] = language;

                if (!rest.StartsWith("~/"))
                    destinationPath = "~/" + rest;
                else
                    destinationPath = rest;

                EasyUrlHelper.Current.OriginalPath = destinationPath.Replace("~/", "");

                HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(string.Concat(destinationPath, queryString == "?" ? "" : queryString));
                return BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(destinationPath, typeof(Page)) as Page;
            }

        }

        return BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath("~/404.aspx", typeof(Page)) as Page;
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It was a configuration issue. The AppPool was set as v4.0 Integrated while it should have been v2.0 Classic.